# Windows boot doesn't show as a option anymore

Tags: windows, boot, bios, filesystem-corruption

so i been with this issue like for 3 days, asked in microsoft community but nothing clear. My laptop was not to good since automatic repair, well for no reason a blue screen appeared and it was taking so long to restart so i just decided to shut down and when i pressed power button again, was on infinite loading, going to bios i discover that windows boot disappeared and now just appear my pen drive with .iso but doenst matter how much i try dont enter anymore in the blue screen with troubleshoot and cmd. any method to take back? the only thing that is opening it's bios and boot manager.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic repair did not work and Windows is not running so a Repair will not work.

First, get the manufacturer's Drive Test App and test your drive.

Then, depending on the drive, get the Operating System download onto a bootable USB Key (you may need to download to a working machine and use Rufus to make the key).

See if you can remove the drive to a carrier in another computer and recover what you can.

Then try to reinstall Windows .